# 2-way TLS with ECC Client Certificates Key and RSA Root Certificate Key

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am setting up a IoT 2-way TLS authentication.

The common way is that both client- and the root (CA) certificate Private Key is RSA.

Now we have devices with limited memory, why we chose to switch to Eliptic Curve Private Keys on the client certificates in the IoT devices. The server certificate remained untouched (RSA).

From my understanding the handshake should succeed. Or do I understand anything wrong? Or do we have to switch the CA certificate to ECC as well?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick test session: It IS possible to use a client certificate with a different private key algorithm than the Root Certificate on the server.

Client: OpenSSL
Server: BoringSSL